# Push data in json array MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, push

I have the following structure in my mondoDB:

```
    "source" : [
            {
                    "source_id" : "800000021",
                    "source" : "Test1"
            }
    ]
    "state" : "AM",
    "owner_phone" : "0",
    "latitude" : 0,
    "leedon_activated" : "True",
    "zip_code" : "12345",
    "fax" : "0",
```

I want to add another json to the source array for the following resut:

```
    "source" : [
            {
                    "source_id" : "800000021",
                    "source" : "Test1"
            },
            {
                    "source_id" : "800000022",
                    "source" : "Test2"
            }
    ]
    "state" : "AM",
    "owner_phone" : "0",
    "latitude" : 0,
    "leedon_activated" : "True",
    "zip_code" : "12345",
    "fax" : "0"
```

What will be MongoDB query for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about $push [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Your code will something like this

```
yourmodelname.update({ /* some conditions to updating files */ },{$push: {"source": {"source_id" : "213123", "source" : "asdasd"}}})
```